# Anyway to make Adobe Air Application keeping the socket open until download finish?

Tags: java, sockets, flash, air, flex3

I'm creating the Adobe Air Application working as Web browser to show the Flex Application as Flash won't be supported by any browser anymore this end of the year.

But there is a file download function in Flex Application called by using ActionForm like below url

> http://localhost:8080/project/action/create

then file will be written in `ResponseOutputStream` like the code below.

```
public void download(Inputstream in, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    OutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"dummy.pdf\"");
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        int len = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while((len = in.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1) { out.write(buffer,0, len); }
    } 
    catch (SocketException e)
    { ...
```

There is no problem if I use any browser to download the file but this exception has been caught if I use Air Application to download.

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket
> write error
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:741)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:347)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:765)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:126)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:574)
> at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:347)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:381)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:370)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)

**Problem:**
I think that after /action/create url is called, air application closed the socket so ResponseOutputStream won't be able to connect to socket.

Is there anyway to keep Air Application open its socket until response has been received ?
I'm trying to keep Flex Application code untouch and this is my first time create Application using Air.
or if the socket is not the real cause, is there anyway I can send back this response to Air Application?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: _"Fails with exception... if I use Air Application to download."_  Not clear how you download with Air. Not clear how to recreate your issue... Did you make a new blank Air project with a `stageWebView` pointing to the html that embeds the SWF file? PS: I added the `Flash` tag for more visibility since others watching that tag might help you.

Comment: @VC.One Thank you very much for tag added and editing. Air application show flex application website using HTMLLoader load the URLRequest and download function on flex will be called when access the action url as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Instead of `HTMLloader` what happens if you use `stageWebView` which is Air's built-in browser engine? If I'm not mistaken it is webkit-based like other major browsers, and you claim your app works in those other browsers. You can see an [example AS3 code here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac3ef1d28412ac57b094b-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac-5a0b8b512ac674f48f-7fff). Use the same URL address that you put into other browsers to see same thing via Air.

Comment: PS: Did the download complete? If still failing then provide a testable link for the Flex app or re-create a similar effect (you can later remove link when a solution is found).